# Category component do api call on created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lifecycle

Currently my category component is making http api call on its creation.

So when I go from my index to category the result of http call is efficient.

But now when I change category so I go from `localhost:8080/category/1` to `localhost:8080/category/2` my component isn't re-rendered so it's not created again and my http call function doesn't fire again how I would like to.

```
    async created() {
        try {
            console.log(this.id);
            const response = await axios.get(`/api/category/getOne.php?id=${this.id}`, axiosConfig);
            console.log(response.data.records[0].name);
            this.category = [response.data.records[0].name];

        } catch (e) {
            this.errors.push(e);
            console.log(this.errors);
        }
    }
```

What do you guys suggest for me, should I place this http call not in `created ()` but for example in `methods {}` and then detect if url id change and execute this function whenever it change? Or there is some better, vue approach for that?

Comment: You should watch `id` value, and for each change trigger the new request.

Comment: Also If you are using Vue router, then you can watch the whole $route object, and when It changes you can make HTTP request with new params,  but you obviously should move this from created hook into the separated method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved above code to `methods {}` and call it on `created()` and on id change like so:

```
created() {
    this.getData(this.id);
},
watch: {
    '$route.params.id'(newId, oldId) {
        this.getData(newId);
    }
}
```

as @Belmin Bedak suggested in comments section.